# Does God forgive those who take his name in vain?

Tags: sin, forgiveness, judgment, ten-commandments, exodus

Christianity teaches the forgiveness of sins by God, but Exodus 20:7, one of the Ten Commandments, says:

> "You shall not take the name of the LORD your God in vain; for **the
>   LORD will not hold him guiltless** that takes his name in vain."

Does this mean that breaking the commandment should be taken as unforgivable by God?

If this sin is unforgivable what implications does that have at the time of judgement?

Comment: *"It says something along the lines of"* That's a weird thing to say when you quoted the Bible directly.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's a Truth Question. It could be easily converted into an exegesis question asking what it means for God to "not hold anyone guiltless".

Answer (score 4):

The only place in the Bible where any sin is mentioned as being unforgivable is in Matthew 12:

> **Matthew 12:31-32** (NLT)
>   31 “So I tell you, every sin and blasphemy can be forgiven—except blasphemy against the Holy Spirit, which will never be forgiven. 32 Anyone who speaks against the Son of Man can be forgiven, but anyone who speaks against the Holy Spirit will never be forgiven, either in this world or in the world to come.

Now the question is if taking God's name in vain is blasphemy or speaking against the Holy Spirit. Personally, I say that it is not because you are not targeting the Holy Spirit, so to speak. I don't quite have Scriptural backup for that, but [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/952/is-saying-oh-my-god-really-using-gods-name-in-vain/953#953) and [that answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/952/is-saying-oh-my-god-really-using-gods-name-in-vain/966#966) on [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/952/58) generally indicate that the answer to that new question is "no".